# Why can you un-upvote/downvote a question but not an answer?

Tags: discussion

So tried un-downvote a answer the other day, but it was locked in, but a question I asked was un-upvoted which did not have any activity for nearly a year.

Why is a question able to be un up or down voted , but an answer is?
Why is this possible?

Comment: I downvoted this meta question because it's based on a false assumption (namely, that you can un-up/down-vote a question but not an answer). Not your fault, of course, but if a post based on a false assumption became upvoted, it might induce the same false assumption in others (e.g. if they see it on the list of Hot Meta Posts).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**There is no difference in behaviour between questions and answers.**

The only reason that [your question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/198503/31394) could be unupvoted was because you had [recently edited it](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/198503/revisions) (so "*which did not have any activity for nearly a year*" is incorrect).

Your vote on any post (question or answer) can be reversed for five minutes; after that they're locked in, but any edit to the post will unlock the vote to be reversed. See also [Why do votes get locked?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80762/278659) on main meta.

Comment: Ahh, I see. So if an edit is made any locked in votes are unlocked. Just for future reference, how long is the unlock open for after the edit?

Comment: @KyloRen Depends what you mean. You can undo a vote at *any* time after the post is edited (the system understands that the post may be different at that point). But if you vote again after editing, then *that* vote is locked in after 5 minutes unless the post is edited again.

Answer (score 2):

Votes are locked in on any post 5 minutes after casting them. An edit on the post unlocks this though so if an edit is made after the vote is cast the voter gets a chance to change the vote or make no vote at all.

Presumably in this case the question has been edited after your vote but the answer not.